# How do I change the price of a flat rate shipping fee depending on a type of Product?

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

I am trying to create a different price for shipping of heavy items. I have light and heavy items and they are categorized via taxonomy heavy/light. How do I change the shipping price via Shipping Rules to detect if its a heavy or light item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to the solution duckx documents is to use a single flat rate and use a rate calculation rule to increase the unit price of the flat rate if the product has heavy products. However, if you need to differentiate in reporting between the number of orders (or total shipping amount) for light vs. heavy, the simplest way is with two separate flat rates.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out .. but not sure if its the best way i think it is. for reference:

1. created a light & heavy shipping flat rate option.
2. added in new conditions matching if its a **heavy** or **light** via taxonomy terms.
3. added in an extra condition for LIGHT shipping to make it disappear by detecting if there is a heavy item in the cart by doing a **negate** on the same above condition.

To make this work you will need https://drupal.org/project/commerce_rules_extra

As you need the **Total quantity of selected product comparison** condition to loop through the entire cart and match what you need in accordance to the terms you select.